# How to allow screenshots with PrevX 3.0

Tags: anti-virus

I'm using PrevX 3.0, which blocks potentially dangerous screenshots from being taken.

It's usually possible to use a dialog to allow a screenshot to be taken; this has now stopped working. Is there a setting in PrevX to change this and globally allow screenshots that I can enable/disable?

I can't find anything in their [online help](http://info.prevx.com/help.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a setting in PrevX SafeOnline.

By setting the **Security Configuration** from Maximum to High, you can allow Screenshots:
[image: PrevX SafeOnline Security Configuration]